# How do I access a group/directory in my Xcode project using the Bundle class?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, directory, bundle

How do I get a path to a group/directory in my Xcode project using the Bundle.path(...) method? I don't want to access a directory in the app's file system, but the directory inside of the project.

I need the path to use with code for a cmusphinx framework. [Here is the GitHub repository.](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx)

Here is the code from the readme of that repository that needs the path to the directory:

```
import TLSphinx

let hmm = ...   // Path to the acustic model
let lm = ...    // Path to the languaje model
let dict = ...  // Path to the languaje dictionary

if let config = Config(args: ("-hmm", hmm), ("-lm", lm), ("-dict", dict)) {
  if let decoder = Decoder(config:config) {

      let audioFile = ... // Path to an audio file

      decoder.decodeSpeechAtPath(audioFile) {

          if let hyp: Hypotesis = $0 {
              // Print the decoder text and score
              println("Text: \(hyp.text) - Score: \(hyp.score)")
          } else {
              // Can't decode any speech because of an error
          }
      }
  } else {
      // Handle Decoder() fail
  }
} else {
  // Handle Config() fail  
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @mag_zbc I have a framework that requires a path to a directory. I would like to point that path to a directory in my Xcode project instead of to a directory in the app's file system. The framework is a cmusphinx framework.

Comment: @mag_zbc I added more information in the post that answers your question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have some resource files embedded in the project and you want to open them? If so, try `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "resourceName" ofType: "resourceExtension")`

Comment: @mag_zbc What do I put for "resourceExtension" if the resource is a group/directory?